# Spring boot - load war file dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, war

I have a main java application in Spring Boot and I would like to dynamically load UI components in some cases.

After some reading, I noticed I can create `.war` project and include it in a tomcat server.

The goal is to load a sub-project only when the user clicks on a specific button in the main application (dynamically).

**My question** - How I can load the a sub project (assuming a .war file where my UI components will be) to my main Java Spring Boot application?

Comment: Are your UI components written in `angular`? Why can't you put your UI artifacts in `resources/static` folder in `springboot` itself. Please provide more details.

Comment: The question is how to load the `.war` / UI components dynamically, I don't want to load it on init as part of the JAR.

Comment: But there can be better solutions than loading the `war` file dynamically if you care to provide specific details.

Comment: @akash I'd love to hear, but which details you think are missing?